# Partial Number SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below query ....

```
SELECT  NGPCostPosition.ProjectNo, NGPCostPosition.CostCat, 
        NGPCostPosition.DocumentNumber, NGPCostPosition.TransactionDate, 
        NGPCostPosition.UnitCost, NGPCostPosition.TotalCost, 
        NGPCostPosition.CreditorEmployeeName, NGPCostPosition.SummaryCostCat, 
        PurchaseNGP_PL.CalculatedCost,
CASE
    WHEN
        DATEPART(MONTH, NGPCostPosition.TransactionDate) = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())  
        AND
        DATEPART(YEAR, NGPCostPosition.TransactionDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
    THEN TotalCost
    ELSE 0
END AS CurrentMonthCost2

FROM  NGPCostPosition INNER JOIN
      PurchaseNGP_PL 
        ON  NGPCostPosition.ProjectNo = PurchaseNGP_PL.PAPROJNUMBER 
        AND NGPCostPosition.DocumentNumber = PurchaseNGP_PL.DocumentNumber 
        AND NGPCostPosition.SummaryCostCat = PurchaseNGP_PL.SummaryCostCat
WHERE NGPCostPosition.ProjectNo = @ProjectNumber 
AND   CostCat ='P070' 
OR    CostCat ='P080' 
AND   NGPCostPosition.ProjectNo = @ProjectNumber 
AND   NGPCostPosition.TotalCost = ABS(PurchaseNGP_PL.CalculatedCost) 

GROUP BY NGPCostPosition.ProjectNo, 
         NGPCostPosition.CostCat, 
         NGPCostPosition.DocumentNumber, 
         NGPCostPosition.TransactionDate,
         NGPCostPosition.UnitCost,
         NGPCostPosition.TotalCost, 
         NGPCostPosition.CreditorEmployeeName,
         NGPCostPosition.SummaryCostCat, 
         PurchaseNGP_PL.CalculatedCost
```

That gives me the below results ...

[image]

What I want to do is limit the column 'ProjectNo' to the first 5 numbers only. (eg. 12169)

Could someone advise if this is possible and what the best way to do this is?

Comment: Just use [Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177601.aspx), e.g. `LEFT(NGPCostPosition.ProjectNo, 5)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT LEFT(NGPCostPosition.ProjectNo, 5) TruncatedProjectNumber, ....
```

Then change your grouping to use `TruncatedProjectNumber`

Answer (score 1):

Well at the cost of space you can provide the first five digits into a separate column.  If you don't want to use the extra space you can try something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(CAST(first_five AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) AS INT)
```

What the above does is converts your numeric into a `varchar`, issues a substring function on that `varchar` than converts those `5` digits back into an int.  It can be a costly operation depending on how often you execute it.  That being said it may be in your best interest to store this value in a separate column, so you avoid recomputing it every invocation.

Comment: I think the inner CAST is not necessary, as from the provided data it's clear that the relevant field is already a string :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a regular thing, then either create a view or use computed columns (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).

As pointed out in the comment, a good way to get the first five characters is using the `left()` function.

Comment: Just what I was going to suggest, if it is very regular, you could make it an indexed view.